# Page numbering only in first page and not in all the document

Tags: page-numbering, article

I am only getting the first page numbered and subsequently it is not numbering the following pages. The error starts after the article title which depicts the abstract and then starts with the text, therefore I cannot use `\clearpage`. 
I have attached some code here.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{article}
    \input{includes/packages}
    \begin{document}

        \input{includes/titlePage}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}

        \section*{\normalsize{ABSTRACT}}
        {\textit{....}}
        \paragraph*{Keywords : }

        \input{./sections/00Introduction}

        \input{./sections/01Section1}


        \nopagebreak
        \input{./sections/05Section5}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Additionally, the problem might be cause from the `includes\titlePage`which I am attaching here:

```
% On the header of the title page
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\lhead{}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{./images/Uni-logo.png} \\\textit{Chair of Uni}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% On the authors and the title of the project
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}
\vspace*{3 mm}
\begin{center}\huge{\textbf{Title of article}}\\[10pt]\end{center}
\begin{center} \textbf{Author}\\[5pt]\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your code snippet provides no evidence that anything would go wrong. We need more information.

Comment: You probably have some `\pagestyle{empty}` in some of your input files.

Comment: @werner I have added some more information from my problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

**`\pagenumbering{gobble}`** is a not-really-good way how to **hide page numbers** (and possibly confuse LaTeX). You seem not to want to hide them, so you probably want to remove this line.

Comment: The error still continues. They instructed me to add this line in order for the page numbering to not repeat twice in the same page, but it seems with our without it, it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, you will probably have to cut down your (probably really huge) document into a [minimal (non-)working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: btw, if you had page numbers appearing twice on every page, something is *seriously* wrong with your document (probably after following some bad advice). Adding more bad code can't solve such an issue.

Comment: No, I meant that I was instructed to, but never tried it before. I am still learning how to use LaTeX.

Comment: @yo' While `\pagenumbering{gobble}` is surely no good idea, I think it's not the culprit here, for right after the `\input`ted file there is another `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. There is surely something else going wrong here...